# multiple useEffect in context file with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I hava a react native app. And I have two api calls: one for the home page and one for navigating from the home page to a other component. But the problem is that if the app loads for the first time both api calls are called. What not has to be - only the api call responsible for building the home page has to be called when the app first time loads.

So I have a service:

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/main_groups/", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const fetchSubCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2/", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

And a context:

```
export const CategoryContext = createContext();

export const CategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [subCategoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [] = useState([]);

    const retrieveCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchCategoryData()
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setCategoryList(results);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    const retrieveSubCategories = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetchSubCategoryData()
                //.then(subCategoryTransform)
                .then((results) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setSubCategoryList(results.subcategories);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(err);
                });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveCategories();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSubCategories();
    }, []);

    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                lue={{
                categoryList,
                subCategoryList,
                loading,
                error,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

So when the app loads first time then this function has to be only loaded: retrieveCategories. But when I look at the backend. I also see that this function is called: retrieveSubCategories.

and this is the component where the user can navigate to a component where the api call: fetchSubCategoryData has to be triggered:

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { category: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

And this is the App.js file:

```
export default function App() {
    const [oswaldLoaded] = useOswald({
        Oswald_400Regular,
    });

    const [latoLoaded] = useLato({
        Lato_400Regular,
        Lato_900Black,
    });

    if (!oswaldLoaded || !latoLoaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CategoryContextProvider>
                    <Navigation />
                </CategoryContextProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>

            <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
        </>
    );
}
```

Question: how to load only the api call: fetchCategoryData when the app first time loads.

oke, If I do it like:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { CategoryList } from "./category.screen";
import { SafeArea } from "../../../components/utility/safe-area.component";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import { SubCategoryInfoCard } from "../components/subcategory-info-card.component";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { fetchSubCategoryData } from "../../../services/category/category.service";

export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.category).then((data) => {
            setSubCategoryList(data);
        });
    }, [route.category]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCatgoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(item)}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <SubCategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: TaskQueue: Error with task : Tried to get frame
> for out of range index NaN

Comment: How does `So when the app loads first time then this function has to be only loaded: retrieveCategories. But when I look at the backend. I also see that this function is called: retrieveSubCategories.` correlate with `useEffect` on MOUNT that calls `retrieveSubCategories();` in `CategoryContextProvider` which basically will always be called on mount?

Comment: @nikita.  This function retrieveSubCategories has to be only triggered when a user navigate from the home component to a other component. But both api calls: fetchCategoryData and  fetchSubCategoryData  are triggered now.

Comment: @nikita. I mean for example I have four, or five, or six, etc api calls. Then all the api calls are triggered by first time loading. That is not the way it has to work I suppose?

Comment: @nikita. I mean is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @RubenSmn. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: It's hard to tell about `normal behaviour` since it depends.. If you want to load all data at the beginnining then do it. Make it acceptable through react context, but in that case I suggest you to either a) optimise your state (since each setState call would cause rerender and you have 4 of them at least) or b) split contexts into several providers. If you want to load later - use Suspense and combine it with data fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to only call the api for the **subcategories** when you navigate to the screen for the subcategories / detail page. By using a `useEffect` to fetch the categories when the `route.category` changes. I used a local state but you can obviously use the setState from the context for this.

```js
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSubCategoryData(route.category).then((data) => {
      setSubCategoryList(data);
    });
  }, [route.category]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Sub Catgories</Text>
      <CategoryList
        data={subCatgoryList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(item)}>
              <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
              </Spacer>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Pass the `id` to the `fetchSubCategoryData` to make it more dynamic

```js
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/${id}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, all you have to do is remove the following lines from your context:

```js
    // remove
    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSubCategories();
    }, []);
```

and then call retrieveSubCategories when you navigate from your home screen, or in the return of a focus effect:

```js
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    return retrieveSubcategories;
  }, []));
```

This would call the function when the home screen is blurred.  Removing it from the context would prevent it from being called when the context mounts.

Comment: Oke, thank you for your help. But where I put useFocusEffect? I think not in the context file.  In the CategoryScreen  you see a navigate function. I have to put it in there?

Comment: Put it on the home screen. Then it will be called when you navigate away from the home screen.